# Checkbox with image and autosize

Tags: vb.net, image, user-interface, checkbox

In `Word 2012` I have seen the following checkbox:

[image]

I am wondering if this checkbox is a .NET control with an image assigned to it (with property "imagealign" being middle right) or if this is a custom solution by MS for their Office GUIs.

I can reproduce the appearance, but I am unable to easily check if the user clicks the checkbox (and wants to change its state) or the info button and wants to show the tooltip.

Also, I have to add some spaces at the end of the checkbox text, else the image is under the text if the checkbox `autosize` property is set to `True`.

I would tend to think that the checkbox is a custom solution by MS or perhaps the image is a separate control.

Does anybody know more about this?

Comment: You should note that Office uses WPF and not Winforms. `equisde` showed below how to do it, but for Winforms but WPF in general offers much more advanced GUI design possibilities than winforms that are worth looking into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for

```
Checkbox.AutoSize = False
CheckBox.Image = "Your Image"
CheckBox.ImageAlign = MiddleRight
```

[image]

But this way you won't be able to distinguish if the user clicks the checkbox or the info button to show the tooltip.

As far as I know, there is no control available at .NET which allows this behavior, so I suppose they are using separate controls.

I think you'll need to use a `PictureBox` near the `CheckBox` and then use `CheckBox_CheckedChanged` and  `PictureBox_Click` events to do whatever you want on each case.

Comment: Well, I do know this workaround, but I was rather looking for an explanation of how MS exactely does this. I guess they do use the autosize property of the checkbox.

Comment: Probably they are using autosize and placing the image based on the placement and checkbox width/heigth

Comment: They first of all use WPF and not the old winforms controls.

Comment: I misunderstood then, sorry. I though you wanted to do that in Winforms. Then I have to refer you to the Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) control library to find some control with these characteristics  --> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752324(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I meant the OP. He did not specify, so I wanted to point the fact out to him before he tries to hard to achieve certain effects in winforms.

Comment: @Jens my mistake. I though it was a comment from the OP :D